# How do i disable the output of spur in my python script

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

I Have a python script as shown below. Basically i want to disable the output of my command (shell.run) because i am unable to execute the continued code.

```
import spur
shell = spur.SshShell(hostname=i, username="mo", password="so")
change = shell.run(["sh", "-c","cd /home/monitor/Emirates-Live/; ./reststart.sh"])
code continued.....
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems i need to use shell.spawn instead of shell.run. Please find the below code

```
change = shell.spawn(["sh", "-c","cd /home/monitor/Emirates-Live/; ./restart.sh"])
```